# How to change the bottom tab icon dinamically in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I would like to know if it's possible to change the bottom tab icon dynamically, I mean, I'm interested to change one of the tab icons when an event occurs...

I have read the documentation but couldn't find any related info about it...

The only solution that I can think of is using a global store variable to control it when it's defined in the bottom tab navigation, using a solution similar to what [react-navigation docs proposes here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/#customizing-the-appearance).

Answer (score 0):

I would also think of using a global state management API such as Context API (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#dynamic-context), redux (https://redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start), recoil (https://recoiljs.org/docs/introduction/installation/), etc.

and then set the global state variable on event handler, as well as in the ternary operator in the react-navigation example you provided (in the place
of "`focused`")